# javascript to hide parameter and navigate to the next page

Tags: javascript

"
                                                                    ONCLICK="javascript:submit();" CLASS="link_btnPrimary">Enroll

When the enroll button is clicked on the page, it navigates to the next page along with parameters as shown above visible on the address bar and the status bar.

I wanted a solution to hide the parameters on the address bar and the status bar, and naigate to the next page too.

Please help me out.

Comment: Wow, you're on a roll today with these obscure questions.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the `<form>`'s `method` attribute is set to `"post"`:

```
<form method="post" ...
```

Comment: @viswa: are you sure? Go check again.